How is the comparison between two objects done with default comparison?
I have been reading up on the default comparison operator, and there is something I don't understand.
Let's say I have the following:
class Rational
{
    public:
        Rational(int numerator, int denominator) : numerator(numerator), denominator(denominator) {}
        friend auto operator<=>(const Rational& lhs, const Rational& rhs) = default;

    private:
        int numerator;
        int denominator;
};

So, this should implement all the comparison operators via one overload, which is very convenient. But, how is the comparison done? Is every corresponding data member of two objects compared when determining the result?
That can't be the case. If I, for example, have this:
Rational rt1{-3, 2};
Rational rt2{3, -2}; 

What would the result of rt1 < rt2 be? rt1.numerator < rt2.numerator but rt1.denominator > rt2.denominator. So how are the two objects really compared?
Disclaimer: I am a big time C++ noob.

One of the approaches to C++ (or any programming language) that has worked well for me is the learning technique of "try it and find out" (in the military known as FAFO).  Did you try it?  What did you observe?  Granted, C++ is not very amenable to FAFO, and is best learned by a good C++ book.

Using the default operator<=> doesn't make sense for a class like your Rational -- one would want to define it to do a proper comparison of the rational values encoded in the class.

The default comparison for a class effectively does a loop over all bases (in left to right order) then non-static members (in declaration order) doing a lexicographical comparison.  Members that are arrays are compared in index order (element 0 before element 1, etc).  The loop stops (aka short-circuits) when the result is known.    For a class representing a rational number, the defaulted operator will not make sense (e.g. two rational values are not necessarily non-equal if their numerators and denominators are non-equal).

As with other areas of the language (such as tuples), the default ordering is lexicographical. This is alluded to in Comparison Operators, including Three-Way Comparison, but it is more clearly (but not crystal-clearly) stated in cppreference.com.
Lexicographical ordering is a generalization of alphabetical ordering. You might recognize that "bus" comes before "school" in alphabetical ordering because 'b' comes before 's' (and the rest of the letters do not matter). Similarly, in lexicographical ordering, comparisons are done until there is a mismatch. The first mismatch determines the order of the whole.
In the case of your Rational class, numerator is declared before denominator. So when two Rational objects are being compared, if the numerator fields are not equal, then that is how the two objects compare. Only if the numerators are equal are the denominators looked at. That is, Rational{-3, 2} < Rational{3, -2} because -3 < 3; the other values do not matter.
If there were any base classes, they would be compared before the data members, still following the principle of looking for the first mismatch.
